# replace text in multiple footer and/or primary footer word vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

i wanted to replace a text in the footer of word doc. Some docs might have only primary header and footer, some have multiple headers and footers.

Here's my code:

```
Sub changedate()

     Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
     ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter    

Check1:
     With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Dec 01, 2015"
        .Replacement.Text = "Dec 01, 2015"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

      ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.NextHeaderFooter
    On Error GoTo Cont
         GoTo Check1


Cont:
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument


End Sub
```

On multiple footer documents it works fine, but if only one footer is available it shows an error.

Comment: What error is coming up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `On Error` up a line in your code.  Otherwise, when you look for the next Footer, none is found and the error takes place BEFORE the code reads the line about how to handle errors.

Edit:  You could also do a `For Each wdPrimaryFooterStory in ActiveDocument.StoryRanges` (not sure the exact syntax on that but this should help: http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm